# how to add smaller in icon in .desktop - file for slingshot?

Tags: slingshot, app-shortcuts

i recently installed sublime Text and I add an .desktop file to open it via Slingshot.

But If I search for sublime slingshot just shows a generic icon.

How can I change the .desktop file to get rid of the generic icon.

Here is the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/home/snowparrot/sublime/sublime_text_3/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=/home/snowparrot/sublime/sublime_text_3/Icon/128x128/sublime-text.png
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Neues Fenster in Sublime
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n


[Desktop Action Document]
Name=Neue Datei in Sublime
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "generic icon"? You Desktop file points to a sublime text icon. But if that icon doesn't exist or the path isn't right the system will default, I assume, to what might be considered a "generic" icon. I'd double check the path you have listed in the icon field.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the [AppEditor app](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor.desktop), it's a Elementary OS specific app that makes editing those desktop files easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the path to your icon file. If it's correct try adding a StartWMClass line to your file. Run xprop WM_CLASS and add the output the the above line.